# How can $5^{\log_{a}b}$ be written as $b^{({\log_{5}a})^{-1}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I tried everything including letting the expression be k, a variety of log laws (change of base) but I can't get the expressions to match. I know that it is in fact true vis calculator

Comment: Taking $a=b=5$, $5^{\log_5 5} \ne 5^{\log_5 5^{-1}}$. So the expression is wrong.

Comment: huh. It works with any other numbers though. Shouldn't it be assumed that a≠b?

Comment: Taking $a=5, b=25$, $5^2 \ne 25^{-1}$.

Comment: Before editing, the question was $5^{\log_a b} = b^{\log_5 a^{-1}}$. Just saying.

Comment: yes, sorry about that. Would it still work now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$5^{\log_ab}=\left(b^{\log_b5}\right)^{\log_ab}=b^{\log_b5\log_ab}=b^{\log_a5}=b^{\left(\log_5a\right)^{-1}}$$

Comment: How did you even get to the first step?

Comment: $b^{\log_b 5} = 5$.

Comment: Ahhhh I see. Very smart

Comment: @user71207 I used a definition of $\log$. Also, I added something. See now.

Comment: Hi, I am also unsure of how you got from step 3 to 4. What log definition are you using?

Comment: @user71207 It's $\log_mn=\frac{\log_kn}{\log_km}.$ In our case: $\log_b5=\frac{\log_a5}{\log_ab}.$

Comment: Ah yes I realized. And you could've also made the "5" the base as well

Comment: @user71207  No! Because we need to get $\left(\log_5a\right)^{-1}$. If we want to solve this problem, we need the base $a$ in the third step.

Comment: I meant making both $$\log_{}5\log_{}$$ base 5 so $$\frac{\log_{5}5}{\log_{5}b}\ \frac{\log_{5}b}{\log_{5}a}$$ = $$\frac{1}{log_{5}a}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$5^{\log_a b}=b^{\log_a 5}~~~(1)$$ can be verifies by taking $\log$ both sides as
$$LHS=\log (5^{\log_a b})=  \log_a b \log 5=\frac{\log b \log 5}{\log a}.$$
$$RHS=\log(b^{\log_a 5})=\log_a 5\log b= \frac{\log b \log 5}{\log a}$$
As $\log_x y=\frac{1}{\log_y x}$, we can write RHS of (1) as
$$5^{\log_a b}=b^{(\log_5 a)^{-1}}~~~(1)$$

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use the laws of change of base act like bellow:

$$5^{\log_a b}=c$$

Take log:

$$\log _a b=(\log _a c)(\log_a 5)^{-1}$$

$$b=(a^{\log_ac})^{(\log_a 5)^{-1}}$$

$$a^{\log_a c}=c$$

Therefore:

$$b=c^{(\log _a 5)^{-1}}$$

Or:

$$b^{(\log_a 5)}=c$$

But:

$\log_a 5=(\log _5 a)^{-1}$

Therefore:

$$c=5^{\log_a b}=b^{(\log_ 5 a)^{-1} }$$